# Forcing table contents to flow

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have used the following CSS style to ensure my content in a table is kept within a specific size:

```
div.tablewrapper {
    height: 290mm;
    width: 200mm;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

And below is the html table codes I am using:

```
<div class="tablewrapper">
<table width="200mm" height="290mm" border="1">
    <tr width="200mm" height="290mm">
         <td>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
     </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

From the above codes, I am trying to constraint a long text inside a div element which works.

The main problem is, how do I force the content to flow downwards instead of disappearing away into the constrainted areas ?

Comment: NB: `<table width="200mm" ...` is not valid HTML. `width` is a HTML attribute and not a CSS property here, and HTML doesn't support units such as `mm`. HTML only knows pixels (`width="200"`) or per cent (`width="50%"`): http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#adef-width-TABLE

Answer (score 0):

Set the table's style to have `table-layout: fixed`, and consider using `word-break: break-all`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Where should I use the word-break ?